# jQuery Wijmo, treeview with attributes from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, wijmo

I want to generate a treeview from a json, but I need to fill. “attr or .date” in the nodes of treeview
how to do?

```
data = [{
  "text": "Item 1",
  "attr": {
    "id": 12145646541 "class": "folder"
  }
}, {
  "text": "Item 2",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "Item 2.1"
  }, {
    "text": "Item 2.2"
  }, {
    "text": "Item 2.3"
  }]
}, {
  "text": "Item 3"
}, {
  "text": "Item 4"
}]

$("#ul_menu").wijtree({
  nodes: data
});

<ul id="ul_menu"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly take a look at this blog article which explains about binding a wijtree to an external datasource as an json object:
http://wijmo.com/populate-wijtree-from-external-data-source-using-knockout/